# Should the questions asked about the terminology of a programming technique or concept be closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Suppose a user knows about the process of Thread Synchronization, but doesn't know that it is named Thread Synchronization. The user explains the process in a question to get the name. Will that be considered off-topic and be closed?

Comment: No, that’s what the [tag:terminology] tag is for.

Comment: No. It should not be considered as off-topic

Comment: @Xufox, are you suggesting that if there's a tag for something, that means it's on-topic? ;)

Comment: Funny @gnat, that duplicate went the opposite direction of this one.

Comment: Personally, I'd be very surprised if using the keywords from a question such as this it wouldn't be possible to more or less quickly find the "_terminology, programming technique or concept_" if the asker knows that such term _exists_ and can more or less describe it. Being so, most questions like this would be at the very minimum not well researched at all. I don't know if off-topic directly, but certainly not something I think we'd like to encourage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions asking about terminology should *probably not* be off-topic.

*If* you want to ask a terminology question, use the [terminology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminology) tag for this.

> Used when a question asks for clarification regarding programming terms.

None of the [“off-topic” close reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) really apply to terminology questions, except:

- for terms that *aren’t* closely related to programming, or are too general,

  > Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow […]
- or for terms that are only related to server administration

  > Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow […]

They’re also generally neither *unclear*, nor *too broad*, nor *opinion-based*, but according to the help center may very well be a *“practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development”*.

And yes, a terminology question *might* have practical implications. For example, knowing the difference between “variable” and “property” can help explain certain behaviors in JavaScript. Knowing what is meant by “assignment”, in general, may help someone understand ownership rules in Rust.

I originally wrote this answer five years ago, and in my opinion, it’s still such a gray area issue that I feel that the merit of the question should be determined by its usefulness, which in turn is determined by its score. Provided this de-facto voting behavior doesn’t cause any problematic disruptions on the site, I feel that terminology questions have potential to add value to our repository of knowledge.

A terminology question could still be downvoted if readers feel that it is not well-researched, or if the description of the term is not clear enough, therefore not easily findable and thus not useful.

Comment: How does a terminology question's answer change how one goes about the practice of writing software? (If it doesn't, it's not strictly speaking practical).

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow *is not* a (reverse) dictionary. We can explain the how's or why's stuff, which is a bolder endeavor than merely a library of definitions. Remember, we give solutions to *practical, answerable problems that is unique to software development*.

The only practical problem of not knowing how something is called is that you have to use more words to communicate, and that's not unique to software development.

Comment: **@Braiam** I joined the community with only one intention, **Know what I don't Know**. So I found it very helpful when I see explanations and the way people write code, and to an extend I believe this community is meant for sharing knowledge. So if I'm asking a question that is related to programming, which gets closed saying that it is off-topic, then what is the relevance of the term **Knowledge Sharing**?

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran not all knowledge is meant to be shared on SO, only a very specific subset, in a very specific format, within a very specific context.

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran you'll probably be disappointed to know that ”Which is a better programming language: A or B" is off-topic here.

Comment: @Braiam, what you said will be right when you are explaining a logic or a process, you should consider the fact that the things you share won't go to wrong hands. But what what can go wrong with telling the name given of  a process, about which a person has some idea except the name.

Comment: @Andrew T, it can be off-topic, may be opinion based also. But that was not the scenario that I was discussing.