# Is a question that asks "for a word that means ..." on topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

My software development teams usually builds an application or a service.  And there are a lot of common elements between an application and a service.

Right now my documentation writes out "application or service" fully.

I want to ask on Stack Overflow for a word that can mean either or both.  But that smacks of a "recommendation", and is not really directly about coding.

Is this a "on-topic" question for Stack Overflow?

Comment: it'd be welcome in various chat rooms on SO,

Comment: related (and the whole dupe target chain): [Should the questions asked about the terminology of a programming technique or concept be closed as off-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361163/should-the-questions-asked-about-the-terminology-of-a-programming-technique-or-c/361174#361174)

Comment: Maybe https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ or https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-writing

Comment: Without further information, words like *service*, *application*, *system*, *provider*, *server*, *architecture*, *platform*, *process*, *interface*, *resource*, *virtual*, *task*, *monolithic*, *autonomous*, *infrastructure*, *transaction*, *message*, *instance*, *proxy*, *state*, *structured* and *environment* are (almost) meaningless in this context. A common technique is to invent your own [TLAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-letter_acronym), but do provide a [glossary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary) so their (well-developed) definitions are easy to find.

Comment: How about... A servication? Or an applice? :D

Comment: Mini-Rmk: "teams" (= plural) + "builds" (= [verb] singular) are grammatically incompatible in a same Sentence...

Answer (score 39):

No. Asking about words in English language is not considered a programming problem. You may check the help section of https://english.stackexchange.com/ as it might be on-topic there.

The only time when it would be on-topic on Stack Overflow would be if that word is the name of the programming language tool or technology.

Comment: In my experience, such questions are usually not well-received on EL&U. @OP if you ask there, try to come up with a different context that is not programming-specific to give your question a better chance. Related discussions: [1](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11630), [2](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7099).

Comment: I achieve to submit a few [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/484129/70403) [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/492264/is-there-a-name-for-all-numbers-different-than-zero)

Comment: @41686d6564  Sometimes well received, but still appropriately closed e.g. What's the correct name for an "association table" (a many-to-many relationship) [closed]  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045034/whats-the-correct-name-for-an-association-table-a-many-to-many-relationship/40623379#40623379

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I was talking about English Language and Usage, not Stack Overflow. Though, you're likely to find well-received ones there too since every rule has an exception :)

Comment: Isn't "naming things" one of the biggest challenges in programming? How is that not on-topic?

Comment: @JanWilamowski It's not that a question on "naming things" on SO is automatically off topic (as long as it related to software development). The tricky issue is how to ask such a question without inviting opinionated answers, because then it is off topic.

Answer (score 33):

Here's a quick guide, for all the sites you might think of posting on:

- Stack Overflow: Off topic
- [Writing](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1401/34330): Off topic
- Software Engineering: Maybe. Maybe not. In my limited experience with this site, such questions do poorly. But you may be able to pull it off. An [SE meta post](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6582) says:

  - On topic: What is the name of this well-known concept?
  - On topic: Questions about "principles of naming things."
  - Off topic: What should I name this thing?
  - For more details, a [more detailed post](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8882) may help
- English SE: Depends. There's a [balance between asking for a "name" and a "word"](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11964/191178), as I point out in that meta post. (I have a hefty amount of rep on this site so my thoughts count for something.) I'll also note that questions that are also even somewhat technical seem to get downvotes and close votes. If you do ask, your tags are [single-word-requests] and [hypernyms].
- ELL: Similar to English SE, but geared towards non-native English speakers. Better if you're looking for a word that would likely be obvious to a native speaker.

Comment: I achieve to submit a few on english.se.com: [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/484129/70403) [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/492264/is-there-a-name-for-all-numbers-different-than-zero)

Answer (score 10):

Questions about wording to use in documentation or user interface are, I think, validly part of UX so direct them to the [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.

eg: [What's a good single-word term that means "a user who's signed in to your website"?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/95088/whats-a-good-single-word-term-that-means-a-user-whos-signed-in-to-your-websit)

Answer (score 6):

As far as I am concerned, terminology questions should be welcome on Stack Overflow if it's about *programming* terminology (and in English, of course).

Comment: too opinion-based though -- wish SO had an option for polls or something like that -- questions without a definite answer but where seeing the number of upvotes on the various answers would be beneficial

Comment: Certainly doesn't need to be opinion based - there are plenty of questions that have definite answers.  "What is the name of the method in a class that is called when an object is instantiated?"

Answer (score 2):

It depends. If the question is about an algorithm, programming problem, or programming tool and it's a "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" and "based on actual problems that [the OP] face[s]", then yes.

In short, if not knowing the term is preventing them from using a programming tool, writing or using an algorithm, or completing a programming problem, then yes. If it's just an open-ended question motivated by curiosity or it's not unique to programming, then it's not.

Answer (score -3):

Word requests are a really tricky bit on Stack Overflow. Questions on Stack Overflow should have a single, canonical, objectively correct answer. Which means, in order to know whether a word request question is on-topic or off-topic, you basically have to know the answer already. (To be more precise, you have to at least know that there *is* a single, canonical, objectively correct answer, i.e. that there is a universally agreed-upon term.)

Comment: I don't think this is true. If it were, then we would also have to reject questions of the form "How do I do X?" if there are multiple ways to do X; we'd have to advise people not to ask such questions unless they already know the answer; etc., etc., etc.

Comment: I'd remove "single" from your list, because we have _many_ a question with many more than one great, useful, helpful answer.

Answer (score -8):

In C# parlance, you're referring to an assembly or DLL.  As assembly could be executable, or be a shared library, where as a DLL by its very name (dynamically linked library) implies it is not executable by itself.

Other languages may use other words like module, or package.  But the nature of the language, be it interpreted or not may influence what it is commonly called.  You may find the language changes depending on how something is used.  A DLL for instance could be a component of a system or it could be middleware, etc.

So that's a lot of different words.  But in all honesty, you should first be asking your developers, not Stack Overflow.  Beyond that, you've not indicated any effort of your own to find out by going to sites such as:

https://www.dictionary.com
https://www.thesaurus.com/
https://reversedictionary.org